# Use JS Variable in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I want to use a JS variable in JSON.

```
var add = mixItems[i][0] + "," + mixItems[i][1];
jQuery.getJSON("wp-content/plugins/proteinmixer/php/addtocart.php" , function(data){
});
```

PHP:

```
require_once('../../../../wp-blog-header.php'); 
header('Content-Type:application/json'); 
global $woocommerce; 
$productId = 66; 
$quantity = 10; 
//$add = $productId.",".$quantity.""; 
//$add = add; 
$addtocart = $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($add); 
echo json_encode($addtocart);
```

I need the variable ADD in JSON.

Comment: What do you mean js variable in Json? Function getJson will return Json object as data in your callback and what do you want to do after? add some fields to this object?

Comment: Your question is not explaining well. do you want json of items? if there are only items like item1,item2,item3. then your can just build an array like ["item1","item2","item3"]. or if you want json only. you can build key-value pair. [{ "item_name" : "item1" },{ "item_name" : "item2" },{ "item_name" : "item3" }].

Answer (score 1):

You can turn any Javascript value/object into a JSON string by using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var add = mixItems[i][0] + "," + mixItems[i][1];
var jsonAdd = JSON.stringify(add);
```